# La pantalla siempre esté activa en ios con swift

Tags: ios, swift

Como puedo hacer que cuando este mi aplicacion, la pantalla del movil no se supenda y siempre esté activa??

Tengo este código, pero no se si es correcto

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true
```

Comment: Mira esto que esta en ingles http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661004/how-to-disable-enable-the-sleep-mode-programmatically-in-ios

Comment: Dejando de lado que tu código es correcto, ¿por qué no lo pruebas? Haz que tu móvil se bloquee al cabo de 1 min, si con esa opción activada no se bloquea, es que funciona...

Comment: a ver esta copcion: abre  Info.plist file y añade Application does not run in background. y le pones YES